# Download from cloud storage bucket without internet

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a requirement to download some files stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The challenge is to download it **without internet access**. Is possible to interact with a Bucket without Internet access? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: Hey there, can you show us some of the code that you written and what precise problem that you are having. I will say that it will *not* be possible to download something from the internet without an internet connection

Comment: Hi Mark, Below is the code which we use to download from cloudstorage but it works only with internet where 'urlPath' is the GCP cloud storage path.
        /home/gcpuser/gsutil/gsutil cp -r $urlPath*INI /sapmedia/

Answer (score 2):

No, it wouldn't be possible. You need internet connection to access resources hosted in the Cloud.

You would need to store the files locally or on a physical data storage device in order to access them without the connection.

The only possible option to not use "internet" is to use [Dedicated Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/concepts/dedicated-overview) where basically you will have a cable from your on-premise to Google's network.

### EDIT:

As I understand from the comment you edited, your actual goal is to connect to your **GCS bucket** from a private **VM instance** hosted on GCE.

For that you might want to use [**VPC Service Controls**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/) to define the security perimeter around your services and constrain data within a **VPC**. One of this product's [**advantages**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview#benefits) is that the VPC Service Controls provides an additional layer of security by denying access from unauthorized networks, even if the data is exposed by misconfigured Cloud IAM policies.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/how-to) you can find the GCP documentation on configuring VPC Service Controls.

Comment: Thanks Denis for the response. We were able to achieve it in AWS by simply creating an s3 end-point....so similar functionality is not available in GCP ? Our entire infra is in Google cloud and we use VPN to connect to the GCE instances. Within these instances we need to download media from cloud storage.

Comment: Your initial question *"download from cloud storage bucket without internet"* seems to be slightly different from what you're trying to achieve. Do I understand it correctly, that what you're trying to achieve is to have a **GCE instance** (without internet access but within a **virtual network**) from which you would be able to connect to your Cloud Storage?